# Upload video to youtube from iOS app--Youtube API

Tags: ios, youtube-api

I am trying to upload videos to youtube and these are the steps I am following:

1)I am visiting google console and I am creating a new project here.
2)Then I am getting an OAuth client id here and that I am passing in my project.
 
3)After that when I try to authorise in my app, it shows that this user is not allowed to authorise.
4)Enabled Youtube APIs.

Everything was working fine until now.What I have done now is that I have changed the associated account with this youtube API and now it doesn't work.I am attaching the screenshot
Now I am using GTMAppAuth and my authentication process is complete.After allowing the permission I am getting authorisation code like this.I know that this authorisation code will be exchanged and an access token will be provided.But which method will do this?What to do now?
[image]

Comment: The text explained it. You need to open the OAuth in Safari and not in the webview.

Comment: How do I do that?I mean its the YouTube library code.

Comment: you need to bypass the webview delegate (shouldstartloadwith) and use [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"oauth url here"]]; to open it in safari.

Comment: I am trying to do this but the delegate(shouldstartloadwith) gets called everytime.If I am writing the safari code inside this delegate,then it shows a screen with a code(please copy this code, switch to your application and paste it there).

Comment: You need to return NO to that delegate.

Comment: Yes I am returning NO,it opens safari with a code on that page

Comment: Any solutions to this???I'm stuck here

Comment: @GeneCode Please can you explain this?I am stuck here

Comment: Can you show what is displayed in safari?

Answer (score 1):

Google has updated its security restrictions for OAuth flow. They are not going to allow native web-views to initiate OAuth flows, but rather are encouraging people to use the OS browsers to do so. In your case, you'll probably have to wait for the Google calendar SDK to update their code to obey the newly recommended flow. More information is available [here](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html)

Comment: Yes I have gone through that and I am thinking of using GTMAppAuth...shall I?

Comment: Try it mate! :)

Comment: post any progress or result mate

Comment: I have ben using GTMAppAuth and I am done with the authentication step, but after I press allow,I see the screen with a code.I am editing my question with updates.